# after login with google and facebook not returning back in ios 7

Tags: ios7, facebook-login, google-signin

As per title in my app i can successfully login with facebook or google account as per tutorial given in  developer.facebook.com and developer.google.com  but problem is that flows not return from browser to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your project's URL Schemes correctly in your info plist?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#configure

The login calls a custom URL that your app has to handle after the authentication is done

Comment: There was problem in URL Types in info tab.
and in google we have to provide builderId with project name. that was problem